# android okohttp insert data into php doesn't work

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, okhttp

Please help.
I want to insert data from android to server (php) using okhttpclient, the code doesn't work.
Please help, I have been for more that 1 day stuck in that

Thank you.

Here's my php code:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","Androidtesting");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
   //insert query

   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];

   $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password)
   VALUES (".$email.", ".$password.");";

   mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}


mysqli_close($con);
```

---

my android code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

                String email = "myemail";
                String password = "mypassword";

                RequestBody body = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                        .add("contentType", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                        .add("email", email)
                        .add("password", password)
                        .build();

               Request request = new Request.Builder()
                       .url("http://10.0.2.2/AndroidTestingProject/data.php")
                       .post(body)
                       .build();

                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                response.body().string();
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new              
IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
}catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("FIL FUNCTION errroros hwa "+e);
                }

        }
    });

    thread.start();
```

Comment: Please copy the error log that you get.

Comment: Please remove the `Please help`s. Of course this forum is to help you. And no thanks now. You can thank when you have been helped.

Comment: There is no error at android studio @iBobb

Answer (score 0):

**Finally I reached an answer..it's in the php code and it should be like follows.**

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
switch ($key) {
    case 'email':
    {
        echo  $firstKey = $value;
    }        
    break;
    case 'password':
        echo $secondKey = $value;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```